# Не передается переменная из jquery в php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть список предприятий, из которого вытаcкивается id каждого в `console.log` при переключении с одного предприятия на другое. Пытаюсь вытащить id на страницу php, таким образом что бы при переключении предприятий id тоже менялся на страницу. Подскажите как это сделать??
То что я пробую:

```js
function OsagoValue(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'order/view.php',
            data: {action: 'OsagoValue',company: $('#company option:selected').val()},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }



        });
    }
```

```html
//view.php
<label class="nbox-span">Выберите предприятие</label>
            <div class="select_ico">
                <select class="form-controlre" name="99999company" id="company" onchange="OsagoValue(); ">
                    //тут идет код выборки предприятий

                        <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
                </select>
           </div>
           
           
           
 <?echo 'Первая переменная: '.$_POST[data].''?>
```

Comment: Так `$_POST[data]` это массив, ищите в нем `_POST['data']['action']`

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov , тут скорее `$_POST['action']` или  `$_POST['company']`

Comment: Не могу не согласится, упустил, что он так и передает. Все верно.

Comment: Да и линк немного не понятен `url: 'order/view.php',` может `./` или `/` В идеале после запроса почитать ответ, вывести в консоль, гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov передается  только `company`, линк я думаю правильный иначе не работало бы

Comment: Тогда, да а сделайте `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```js
$('#company').change(function(){

  var companyId = this.value, 
      postData = new FormData();
      
  postData.append('action','OsagoValue');
  postData.append('company', companyId);
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'order/view.php',
    data: postData,
    cache: false,
    /*Опции для типа данных отправляемых на сервер*/
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    /**/
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="company" class="nbox-span">Выберите предприятие</label>
<div class="select_ico">
  <select class="form-controlre" name="99999company" id="company">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!--
  содержимое обработчика view.php
  <?
    echo $_POST['action'].' , '.$_POST['company'];
  ?>
-->
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Евгений Пивоваров , добавил опции для типа данных. У меня работает.